# Windows Phone 8.1 system logs

Tags: logging, windows-phone-8.1, operating-system, background-task

I am having a rely hard time with my BackgroundTask, it seems to be terminated by the OS.

I cannot trust the Log, cause sometimes the BackgroundTask terminated in the middle of the line...

Is there any way to take a look at Windows Phone 8.1 system logs, or any other equivalent options?

Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there are no system logs for windows phone 8.1.  You can use something like application insights, hockey app, xamarin insights, splunk mint, little watson to get better error messages for troubleshooting.

http://hockeyapp.net/features/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andypennell/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/
http://insights.xamarin.com/
https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1885/

Comment: OK, thank you very much

Comment: There is also a nice post : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dougste/2016/05/19/troubleshooting-exceptions-in-a-windows-phone-app/